# get distance from dragged element to other related element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I might have a very specific question about `jQuery`'s `draggable()` in combination with css.
I have lots of `divs` in my body which are all draggable:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        var randomleft = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        var randomtop = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        var appenditem = '<div id="cube'+i+'" style="position: absolute; border: 2px #000 solid; left: '+randomleft+'px; top: '+randomtop+'px; width: 15px; height: 15px;"></div>'
        $('body').append(appenditem);
        cubes.push($('#cube'+i));
    }

$('div').draggable();
```

So far so good.

Then I have a fixed `<div id="fixed">` in my body at a specific position, lets say: `top: 50px; left: 50px;`

What I would like to do is trigger the event handler on `dragstop` and get the distance between the currently dragged div on dragstop to the fixed div.

For example on dragend a div is dragged to: `top: 500px; left: 40px` then I would like to have the values: `+450` and `-10` because the div was `top: +450px` and `-10px` from  `#fixed`.

How can I do this, and especially the negative value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to take in consideration the `#fixed` height and width?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes but all divs have to same size so I can simply add that value

Comment: oh, ok than, I did it without that detail, just add that math as you desire. Take a look at my demo, hope will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IqupOrA/2/edit)**

```
jQuery(function($) {

   var allCubes  = '',
       $fixed    = $('#fixed'),
       fixedOffs = $fixed.offset();

    for(var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        var randomleft = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
            randomtop  = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        allCubes += '<div id="cube'+i+'" style="position: absolute; border: 2px #000 solid; left: '+randomleft+'px; top: '+randomtop+'px; width: 15px; height: 15px;"></div>';
    }  

    $('body').append(allCubes); // Outside loop! (60% more performance)

    $('[id^="cube"]').draggable({
        stop: function(ev, ui){
            var pos = ui.position; // or use ui.offset if you need document related position
            // var orgPos = ui.originalPosition; // if you need it
            alert(
               ( pos.left - fixedOffs.left )+' \n '+
               ( pos.top  - fixedOffs.top  )
            );
        }
    });  

});
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. Works like a charm. Didnt know that performance thing, im not that into debugging!

Comment: and if we are at that topic. why did you use two variables for `$('#fixed').offset()`. Does it have performance reasons too?

Comment: You're welcome! I did some tests long ago, appending with jQ elements 1 by 1 inside a for loop. 60% slower than doing it once outside the loop (appending only once the created string). If your elements is not going to change positions, getting your fixed offset once it's also faster. `fixedOffs` is now an object with accessible `top` and `left` property names.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using jQuery, all you need is the [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) of your fixed element. The draggable `ui` object in the stop callback provides this information as well, the rest is simple math:

```
// assuming the stop callback of draggable()
stop: function( event, ui ) {
    var fixedOffset = $("#fixed").offset();

    return {
        top: ui.offset.top - fixedOffset.top,
        left: ui.offset.left - fixedOffset.left,
    }
}
```

With the values of your example this function would return an object literal with the following values: `{ top: 450, left: -10 }`

Comment: sorry but how, or where can I catch this value? could you please edit your answer with a log or alert. That would be great!

Comment: @supersize did you happen to look at the code (and the return statement)? It's all there…